# HTML+CSS- top navigation bar and text between 2 images

Tags: html, css

I am trying to have both recycle bin images next to the text "recycle". Also trying to place my top nav bar in the middle of the page. Tried many forms of code but not getting the results im looking for, hoping someone can help me out.

First set of code relates to the nav bar.

Second set of code relates to the images that needs to be beside the text.

See the image attached for reference.
[image]

```
<style>
body {
  margin: 3em;
}
.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #fbefb3;
  position: fixed;
  text-align: center;
  top:0;
}

.topnav a {
  float: none;
  color: #14ab3f;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color:  transparent;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.topnav a.active {
    color: black;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

</style>
```

---

```
<div>
    <img class="img1" src="recyclebins.png" alt="">
</div>
<div>
<img class="img2" src="recyclebins.png" alt="">
</div>
<div class="c"><p style="color:#14ab3f"><b>R&nbsp;e&nbsp;c&nbsp;y&nbsp;c&nbsp;l&nbsp;e</b>
</p></div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly sure if this is what you're looking for...

To place the text between 2 images.
**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bnxckt95/2/)**

Navbar not being on top of your page. - It's difficult to guess without your HTML. But here's a wild guess.

```
.topnav {
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   background-color: #fbefb3;
}
```

Comment: Changing my code to include position fixed helped with the placement of the nav. Now my issue is i need to center the whole nav bar in the middle of my website, currently its onto the left, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```css
 body {
            margin-top: 0px !important;
        }

        .top-nav {
            position: -webkit-sticky !important;
            position: sticky !important;
            top: 0 !important;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            background-color: #fbefb3;
            padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
        }

        .top-nav div {
            margin-right: 20px;
            margin-left: 20px;
        }

        .sub-section {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
        }
```

```html
 <div class="top-nav">
        <div>item 1</div>
        <div>item 1</div>
        <div>item 1</div>
        <div>item 1</div>
        <div>item 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="sub-section">
        <img src="./sample.jpg" alt="img 1">
        <p>Some Text Here</p>
        <img src="./sample.jpg" alt="img 2">
    </div>
```

**Hope this will help You**

Answer (score 0):

You could create a container `div`...

```css
nav {
height: 4em;
width: 100vw;
}

#navTop {
height: 1rem;
width: 100%;
background: #14ab3f;
}

#navBottom {
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div id='navTop'></div>
  <div id='navBottom'>
    <img src='https://via.placeholder.com/50' alt='' />
    some text
    <img src='https://via.placeholder.com/50' alt='' />
  </div>
</nav
```

Answer (score 0):

To your nav bar, try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: green;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: brown;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```